# how to modify a database (mysql) and restore it after 5minutes?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, e-commerce

I would like to decrement a value (number of product in stock) when a user clicks on a button "add to cart", and restore the value to the initial value after a time (let's say 5minutes) ?
P.S : im using PHP jquery and ajax.

Comment: Save the value on a file (or a diff table) and use a cronjob to restore it.

Comment: sorry i can't see what you mean, can you be more specific ? (an example would do fine), thank you !

Comment: `UPDATE table set col_x = col_x -1 WHERE col_y = 'z' AND date < NOW() INTERVAL 5 MINUTE` - that oughta do it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Please,  make that an answer...

Comment: @PedroLobito lol I typed that up *on the fly*. Putting that in as answer will only open up a big can of *you know what*.

Comment: @PedroLobito However, if Tarik thinks the same, then I will. Thanks for the offer though ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- would that change the value only for 5 minutes and then it goes back to its initial value automatically??

Comment: @TarikKaoukab No, it won't bring it back automatically. That'll take some guru query, which would most likely consist of a trigger.

Comment: so do you suggest that i create a trigger (after update) on mysql that waits for 5 seconds and then replace the new value by the old one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PDO` (php communication with MySQL). One such example would be to decrease the value in the database with a **prepared statement** to improve **performance** (and **security** of course):

```
$sql = "UPDATE myTable SET number_of_products = number_of_products - :quantity WHERE product_id = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':quantity', $quantity);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Then, since you already prepared the statement, you could revert this value as follows (without having to re-declare the whole sql statement)

```
$stmt->bindParam(':quantity', -$quantity);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

If you wanted the second script to take place after 5 minutes, you could have a queue system implemented that has a delay of 5 minutes for instance. There are also functions that can be used to sleep for 5 minutes, however it would be very unpractical to have that function run on the same page as the user (unless you plan on using it in a separate script) since the user would literally have to be on the same page for 5 minutes waiting.

Comment: it's a nice idea, but the whole waiting part is not so practical, in fact im willing to make this "5minutes" goes on the backstage, while the client is still on my website, doing any kind of stuff he wants, and once he goes there for more than  5minutes, the values would change...

Comment: @TarikKaoukab yes as I said, it's not practical to have someone waiting, which is why a queue system might be practical. I'm not sure how much time and effort you are looking to put into developing your project so I'm just throwing to you some of the ways people implement "waiting" schemes. Regarding the code, the SQL presented is pretty much the standard now-a-days because of how fast it is. Oh and if  my answer worked for you, please accept it with a green checkmark so that future users know that it worked for you.